# r/askhistorians

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The [AskHistorians subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians) seems to have more specialists and more activity (but also more noise) than this SE.

Googling through this meta and that subreddit makes me think the two communities aren't aware of each other.

This site seems to [lack experts](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208/what-can-we-do-to-improve-the-site), perhaps we can poach some of theirs?

(If nothing else, cross-posting a few of their less inane questions here might push our [questions per day](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5169/history) into "healthy" territory.)

Answer (score 4):

Copying an [answer](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1253/56) by Robert Cartaino on a related question elsewhere:

> This can be an effective means of gaining notoriety for a site **if** you approach it with the right mindset. Instead of setting out to simply "re-ask" questions on this site, look for ways of "helping experts" as a means of gaining notoriety of this site. That doesn't mean raiding forums, but seeking out to bloggers and other experts you can help right here.
>
> From the blog post — [**Helping The Experts Get Answers**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/):
>
> > > Reach the right kind of publications and bloggers. Make sure that the key experts in every field know about the site; not just the “Martha Stewart” big names; we want to talk to the people who go to these conferences.
> >
> > But how do you reach writers, bloggers, and other notable experts in the field?
> >
> > **Help them get answers to their questions, too!**
>
> When you ask (and answer) those questions, be sure to close that loop and bring what you learned back to the real world. Let people know what you are doing right here by helping them with *their* problems. That's how this works.

Also, be careful that you don't come across as spammy. That will ruin History.SE's reputation there. Don't just re-ask questions, but try to help out the experts thee instead. It's not really about the QPD stat. In fact, let me include the last paragraph by Robert:

> *And for the love of god, stop flippin' watching those largely meaningless stats in Area 51. This site is doing fine. You know because users are asking good questions, getting good answers, and generally having a good experience with this site. How do you have a "precipitous drop" when you've been open for two weeks? Yeesh, already.*

Don't be to concerned about the stats. The SE team takes more into account than that when considering a site for graduation. Hitting the right numbers there is not necessarily a 'switch' to exiting beta. We need high quality answers and experts. This idea can help with that, but it can be approached with the wrong mindset. We're not copy-pasting answers to raise the QPD stat. We're attracting more experts by helping them out with their problems.

Comment: I agree with your observations for the most part. However, the last quote regarding the Area 51 stats is a bit out of context. I believe that comment was made over a year ago when we first went into beta. Now that we are a full year into it, the stats ARE relevant. We are doing fine on everything EXCEPT questions per day, which is only 4.4, compared to the ideal goal of 15. I think if we could double that number, we would be able to move out of beta a lot faster.

Comment: Yes, but there's more to the stats than that. You should be able to see all the other stats in the "analytics" tab" of the mod tools. There are many more stats. Also, the devs are going to look at question and answer quality. Perhaps a little out of context, but the stats are not everything.

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion is that it might be advantageous for us to cross-post some of their questions. I agree that the two communities don't know about each other, and this might actually be a way of introducing the two. If we can specifically concentrate on questions that are not getting answered, I think that would be a good first start. Then if we are able to answer the question here, we could go to their site and provide a summarized answer with a link back to our site.

Doing this would accomplish a couple of different things. First of all, it would start to raise awareness in their community about us, which may result in more visitors with more expertise. Secondly, it would provide us with more physical links to our site, which is an important method for improving your relevancy with search engines.

The only area in which we really appear to be struggling is in the number of questions per day. I would like to see us raising that number if we can, and this just might be a way for us to do that.

Comment: I started going through the questions, with the intention of cross posting the ones I found interesting and I gave up after I realized that all the questions I picked were sufficiently answered on Wikipedia. From the (limited) amount of questions I checked, cross posting would probably be a bad idea. Still, there might be some hidden gems in there.