# Why history is still in beta?

Tags: discussion

I see in the title that the history stackexchange site is still in beta.

It went way past its 100 days of beta, why it is still in beta?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I understand it, there isn't really a 100 day deadline. They **do** want to see *progress* by the end of that period though. Apparently we had enough for SE to keep us going. There was a fair bit of discussion on this topic in my question [How are we doing?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202/how-are-we-doing)

There certianly has been steady progress since then. Sadly, now that I'm a moderator I'm not supposed to be giving out details of such things, but my answer to [What Can We Do To Improve the Site](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208/what-can-we-do-to-improve-the-site) has several updates gathered from public data. You can compare that to [our current Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5169/history) and see for yourself.

My personal hope is that we come out of Beta sometime soon. I have no special knowledge backing this up, mind you. However, I like the vector we're on.

Comment: 90 days is the _minimum_ period a site can stay in beta, and there's no upper limit. [Personal Finance and Money](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money) has been in beta for 914 days, for example.

Comment: well, SE being open source it's in perpetual beta, so maybe it's an honorary title :)

Comment: @T.E.D. just curious: Do you have to sign some non-disclosure-agreement (or similar) when becoming a StackExchange moderator?

Comment: @Drux There is a moderator agreement you are supposed to agree to. It seems more like a TOS than a full-blown legal agreement though. Mostly I suspect it is to protect *them* when(if) they decide to terminate your mod privs for some reason.

Comment: @Drux The mod agreement is public: http://history.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement

Comment: @jwenting SE is _not_ open source.

Comment: As a software engineer I can categorically state beta is the worst word computer science ever gave to the English language. When software is in use, by definition it is not beta, so calling it "beta" is just dumb. It is like people who put "Under Construction" notices on their web site. Look, if you have a crappy car, you don't need to put a bumper sticker on it that says, "Sorry, I have a crappy car." We don't need to be apologizing for the site. Take the dump beta thing off.

Comment: "I hope we can come out of beta sometime in the next 6 months" - famous last words

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine - LOL. Well, cockeyed optimisim there. I'm gonna edit that, because its obsolete, and as I said I have no input on that decision, nor any better insight on it than any other user here. However, we've continued to improve since then, and now the only real problem area statistically is questions per day (and that's way better than it was). IMHO, we are ready, but it probably wouldn't kill us to wait until our questions per day inches up over 5.

Comment: Aw, why did you remove it? I thought it was pretty funny :P

Comment: I'm seeing 6.3 questions per day currently in the Area 51 stats... What would be the current target for rising out of beta?

Comment: @AllInOne - This answer was accurate at the time, but is obsolete now. Look at [this question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3351/why-is-history-still-in-beta/3352#3352) for more modern info on this topic.