# Community Goal: Answer at least half of the Unanswered Questions on the main site by the end of November

Tags: discussion, pledges, unanswered-questions

I am proposing that we as a community make a commitment to answer half of the [Unanswered Questions](https://history.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) currently on the site. There are 51 as of today, October 25th, which gives us almost 45 days to answer the said questions. That is less than a question a day. I commit to answering at least two of these questions.

Comment: Let's get this site out of beta! +1

Answer (score 6):

I like your goal and I'm happy to participate. However, we are ahead of the required number of answers to get out of beta. We need to have at least 90% answered, and we currently have 94% answered.Our problem is not getting enough questions.

I'd rather see everyone contribute at least one question by the end of November. We ned to be averaging 15 questions per day, but we are currently at 2.5. They identify 5 per day as a low point that needs work, and we are doing only half of that. More questions means a better likelihood that we will get more people coming back to answer them, and that is what will get us out of beta.

[Here are our current stats.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5169/history)

Comment: That is an excellent point, and I was just looking at the stats today. I should have caught that, but I didn't.

Comment: Agreed, I went through answering many of the older, unanswered questions awhile ago but the problem is some are unanswerable in their current form, very specific and hard to find sources for or the OP has not logged in for awhile so even if you have an answer it may never get selected.  Still I like the idea

Comment: Dont care too much about the 15Q/day. Many graduated sites don't have 5Q/day at all, visits per day is much more important. Actually our stats are quite good compared to many other beta sites

Answer (score 2):

Backing up Hauser's comment to another answer here...

IMHO once our visits per day get high enough, the rest of the stats will probably take care of themselves.

I was just looking at this yesterday. Our visits per day is now more than twice what it was [when I first asked about this](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202/how-are-we-doing) back in the wake of the mass-beta closings six months ago. On May 3 (2012), Steve Drennon reported it as 341, and [it is right now](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5169/history) 881. I betcha that if we can get that up into the "Excellent" range of 1500 or more (**legitimately**, not by having folks hit the reload button all day), everything else will naturally improve enough that we'll get ourselves out of beta.

IMHO, if you want to help that along the best things to do are:

1. Ask good **timely** questions and supply high-quality answers when same are asked.
2. Share good questions on the other social media sites you hang out in.

Google ranks websites in its searches by amount and quality of incomming links to them, so #2 is very important to driving traffic into here.

I like our trend here; we just have to keep improving.